# What is the fastest way to compute the F-score for a million annotations?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

Imagine you want to predict certain "events" (coded as: 0,1,2,3,...,N) within a finite number of sentences (coded as: 0,1,2,...,S) of a series of papers (coded as 0,1,...,P).

Your machine learning algorithm returns the following file:

`paper,position,event
0,0,22
0,12,38
0,15,18
0,23,3
1,1064,25
1,1232,36
...`

and you want to compute the F-score based on a similar ground truth data file:

`paper,true_position,true_event
0,0,22
0,12,38
0,15,18
0,23,3
1,1064,25
1,1232,36
...`

Since you have many papers and millions of those files, what is the fastest way to compute the F-score for each paper?

PS Notice that nothing guarantees that the two files will have the same number of positions, the ml algorithm might mistakenly identify positions that are not in the ground-truth.

Comment: Can't you use a database system that is optimized for fast access?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I think any bottleneck you'll have would be caused by accessing the files and reading them into memory. You could ask about taking the average mean of values distributed over a large number of files and get the same answers as for this question. It's not really about optimizing FScore calculation but access to data. Have a look on how statistical measures are calculated in Big Data.

Answer (score 1):

As long as entries in two files are aligned so that you can directly compare line by line, I don't see why it will be slow to process millions of row in O(n) time, even on your laptop.

Comment: Thanks. But nothing guarantees that the two files will have the same number of options. I mean, that is something the algorithm should be looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure about the question then. Let's say your ground truth is "0,0,22", what could be possible output from your prediction? "0,0,21", "0,1,22", "0,2,20" or nothing? How do you define true negative and false negative?

Comment: The proper way to do it is to consider the number of papers (i.e., the first column) as fixed. Given one paper, you may have, say, 2 true positives (i.e., where the position and value are correct), and 3 false positives (either position or value is wrong), and 1 false negative. Does this make more sense to you? The problem is  that the algorithm may return a lot of false positives. One approach could be to generate a file for all papers X all positions, but it will cost lots in terms of memory.